# Can't put sqlite query into separate lists python

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I have sqlite and I query two columns from a table like this:

```
result_set = conn.execute("SELECT time, MeanCurrent from MEASUREMENTS")
```

then, I want to put each column into a separate list, what I'm doing so far is this:

```
list1 = [record[0] for record in result_set]
list2 = [record[1] for record in result_set]
```

The problem is that, while list1 prints the first column perfectly, list2 appears empty, while, if I remove the first line, list2 prints the second column perfectly as well!

So it's like, after the first line execution, something changes in my query but I don't know what.

Is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: I don't know enough Python to express this with actual syntax, but I would define the arrays, then have a loop to iterate over the `result_set` and `push` the fields of the `record` into the list arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`conn.execute()` returns a cursor object. You can't iterate over a cursor more than once; when you reach the end, it won't start at the beginning again when iterating a second time. Either load all rows into a list first, or use a different technique that only needs to iterate *once*.

I'd use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up columns:

```
list1, list2 = zip(*result_set)
```

but you could use `results = list(result_set)` or `results = result_set.fetchall()` to materialise all rows into a list first, or you could use a single loop that uses `list1.append()` and `list2.append()` to add the column values to the two lists.

Comment: Thank you very much, spent so much time trying to figure this out!